# Using 'function' to create custom data frames

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a very large data frame that I want to pull from to make smaller data frames based on specific conditions, but I'm not sure how to do this effectively.  My data frame looks like this (but with hundreds more variables):

```
A      B      C    D
CAT    ABC    5    7
COW    DEF    5    8
DOG    GHI    5    8
BAT    JKL    5    8
MAN    MNO    6    8
HAT    PQR    6    8
```

What I would like to do is create a data frame like this:

```
CAT.ABC.5.7 <- subset(df, A=="CAT", B=="ABC", C==5, D==7)
COW.DEF.5.8 <- subset(df, A=="COW", B=="DEF", C==5, D==8)
```

etc.

It is important that I have the data frames labeled like this so I can quickly "pull" them later based on the values I need.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have "hundreds more variables", do you plan to string them all out like that `CAT.DOG.TREE.5.7......WOTSIT.Q.FVAL`?

Comment: Frank.  No, I anticipate it would be (at most) 3 or 4 variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `interaction` + `split`:

```
split(df, interaction(df, drop = TRUE))
## $CAT.ABC.5.7
##     A   B C D
## 1 CAT ABC 5 7
## 
## $COW.DEF.5.8
##     A   B C D
## 2 COW DEF 5 8
## 
## $DOG.GHI.5.8
##     A   B C D
## 3 DOG GHI 5 8
## 
## $BAT.JKL.5.8
##     A   B C D
## 4 BAT JKL 5 8
## 
## $MAN.MNO.6.8
##     A   B C D
## 5 MAN MNO 6 8
## 
## $HAT.PQR.6.8
##     A   B C D
## 6 HAT PQR 6 8
##
```

If you really wanted to create separate `data.frames`, then do:

```
list2env(split(df, interaction(df, drop = TRUE)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Ananda, Thanks. But I want to specify the specific variables that will go into making each data frame.  There are hundreds of other variables that will be subsetted dependent on these 3-5 variables.

Comment: @Orion Just pass the relevant var names like `split(DF, interaction(DF[c("A","B","C","D")], drop=TRUE))`, I think.